# Use ifstream to read a text file with random generated numbers in columns and find the minimum and maximum from the list?

Tags: c++, file-io, ifstream

I am creating a school project but seems lost at the moment. Can someone help me figure out my problem? Here's what's going on:

I have a program that outputs a random generated numbers in a text file using ofstream. It is generated with a format of two columns (one column is SalePrice & the second column RegularPrice). My problem is creating a code that will do the following:

1. Create a function that will read the text file generated by the first program
2. Find the average of the second column ONLY! (Regular Price) then outputs it in the screen
3. Find the minimum and maximum of the second column ONLY! (Regular Price) then outputs it in the screen

Please help! I need help how to code the ifstream part, I am new to C++ and have tried all the solutions in many books but doesn't seem to work for my needs? :-( Any help will be greatly appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Here's just the section of my code (not the entirety), it is not giving me an error . . . it is simply not giving me anything:

```
 float SalePrice[userInput];
 float RegularPrice; 
 string cPrice;
 string readFile;
 int count = 0;
 ifstream inputFile;
 inputFile.open(fileName);
 inputFile >> RegularPrice;

 // To get you all the lines and place the line from myfile into the line variable
 while(!inputFile.eof() && getline(inputFile, readFile))
 {
      if (count < userInput)
      {
           inputFile >> readFile;
           readFile += cPrice; // Saves the line in STRING.

           //display the line we gathered:
           cout << cPrice << endl;
      }
      ++count;
 }

 avgRPrice = RegularPrice / userInput;

 cout << endl;
 cout << fixed << setprecision (2);
 cout << "The average of all the Regular Prices in the file is: " << avgRPrice << endl;
 cout << "The minimum Regular Price in the file is: " << minRPrice  << endl;
 cout << "The maximum Regular Price in the file is: " << maxRPrice  << endl;
```

EDITED:
Here's my current code for finding the max & min:

```
int maxRPrice(float RPrice[])
{
     if (RPrice > maxRPrice)
         maxRPrice = RPrice;

     return maxRPrice;
}

int minRPrice(float RPrice[])
{
    if (RPrice < minRPrice)
        minRPrice = RPrice;

     return minRPrice;
}
```

Comment: Please post the content of the file you want to read in; this makes it much easier to help you.

Comment: At what point in the above code do you even *attempt* to read the actual `float` values out of your file? You might start with that.

Comment: @WhozCraig I thought I was reading a file using the while loop :-/

Comment: @MKCATT you are.. but putting the values... where? All this does is read a `readFile`, appends `cPrice` (an empty string as it is never given a value) to the string just read, outputs `cPrice` (still empty) to stdout, and then subsequently throws away `readFile`. Only once to you read anything into `RegularPrice`, and `userInput` is neither declared nor apparently defined anywhere in this code (but it is used, strangely).

Comment: @WhozCraig Gotcha! I understand it now. Thanks! By the way, any advice on how to get the minimum and maximum? I posted my current code above.

Comment: Yeah, for starters, those aren't even valid C++ code. Second, you need to know how many items are in each array. (i.e. you have to pass a size parameter as well as the array, then loop to find the appropriate min and max respectively).

Comment: Were I to do this, it would probably be [something like this](http://ideone.com/CQfqAl). Hope it helps.

Comment: @WhozCraig Thank you for the reference. It was helpful! However, can you explain line 57: for (auto val : SalesPrice). I never seen the keyword "auto" before. What does this line actually do? If this the same as the generic loop I know [i.e. for(int i = 0; i < userInput; i++)]?

Comment: @its a C++0x3 thing. It is allowed on anything that exposes a forward iterator supported with `begin()` and `end()` members (and some native types too, such as fixed arrays, but thats another matter). Saves me the trouble of creating an iterator variable long-hand. If your compiler was built anytime in the last three years it probably likes it, otherwise, spelling out an iterator is the logical alternative.

Comment: @WhozCraig Sorry. I'm confused :/ what loop I can substitute to this for (auto val : SalesPrice) in order to get the min/max?

Comment: @MKCATT I updated the source at the provided link. Look at that loop now, and it will be obvious why `auto val : SalesPrice` is simpler.

Comment: @WhozCraig Thank you for all your help! I finally got it! :-)

Answer (score 1):

Here is an improved version of your code which works perfectly for me:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
     const int userInput = 2;
     float SalePrice[userInput];    //Make an array
     float RegularPrice[userInput]; //Make an array

     string readFile;

     ifstream inputFile;
     inputFile.open("yourFile.txt");
     if(!inputFile){ //Check wether the file is open
         cout<<"Couldn't open file!" << endl; 
         return -1;
     }
     // To get you all the lines and place the line from myfile into the line variable
     for(int count = 0; !inputFile.eof() && (count < userInput) ; ++count) //Why are you using a while-loop if you need to count the iterations
     {    
          //
          inputFile >> SalePrice[count] >> RegularPrice[count]; //loads column SalePrice/RegularPrice into the array at position 'count'

     }

     float sumRegularPrice = 0; 
     for(int i=0; i < userInput; i++)
         sumRegularPrice += RegularPrice[i];

     float avgRPrice = sumRegularPrice / userInput;

     cout << endl;
     cout << fixed;
     cout << "The average of all the Regular Prices in the file is: " << avgRPrice << endl;
     //cout << "The minimum Regular Price in the file is: " << minRPrice  << endl;
     //cout << "The maximum Regular Price in the file is: " << maxRPrice  << endl;

     system("pause");
     return 0;
}
```

Why are you loading *RegularPrice* only once? As far as I got your explanation about the file format (you said `one column is SalePrice & the second column RegularPrice`), every line might have this content:

```
3.44 5.99
```

To get the min and max price you can simply write two functions.

With this input:

```
3.44 5.99
5.54 8.99
```

I get this output (in the console):

```
The average of all the Regular Prices in the file is: 7.490000
```

If you have some questions don't hesitate to ask me.

Comment: Works like a charm! Thank you so much @ThunderStorm. By the way, I tried to use two if statements to get the min and max. Unfortunately, the max was populating . . . but NOT the min. It is giving me an output of 0.00. Will you help me or give me a hint for the two functions you've mentioned to get the max & min price? Thanks in advance!

Comment: `.eof()` doesn't do what you think it does in this code, and has no business being in the control expression of that for-loop.

Comment: @WhozCraig I deleted that part of the section since my Prof said the same thing last week about .eof() but the program still works!

Comment: @MKCATT It works only because of `count` being limited by a fixed value. As soon as you added a third or fourth (or thousand'th) entry in the input file, this won't work.